# Not able to run a NEAR RPC node

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to run a NEAR RPC node following this documentation https://near-nodes.io/rpc/run-rpc-node-without-nearup on testnet.

But at step 6, **Run the node**, the process is killed.

```
$ ./target/release/neard --home ~/.near run
2023-04-04T12:44:01.993099Z  INFO neard: version="1.32.2" build="1.32.2" latest_protocol=59
2023-04-04T12:44:02.002627Z  INFO config: Validating Config, extracted from config.json...
Killed
```

I used tags 1.32.2 to release neard on a debian 11.

I  didn't find logs or other info on why it's killed.

Comment: Check dmesg logs. Most probably you run out of memory

Comment: Thanks @VladFrolov it was the issue. Now getting error **Database version 35 is created by a newer version of neard, please update neard**